# How can I use typeid with a template

Tags: c++, c++14

I am trying to provide more type safety by checking what kind of type is passed into a template. Further, this affects the constants used in a computation (in this example machine-epsilon)

My issue is `typeid` seems to emit some strange type in this case.

```cpp
// compile with g++ -Wall -g -std=c++14
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

#define MYFLOAT float

template <typename FLOAT_T>
const double mach_eps = std::numeric_limits<FLOAT_T>::epsilon();

double gamma(const std::type_info& float_t, long long int n)
{
    double eps;
    if (typeid(float_t) == typeid(double)) {
        eps = mach_eps<double>;
    } else if (typeid(float_t) == typeid(float)) {
        eps = mach_eps<float>;
    } else {
        std::cerr << "gamma: unsupported floating-point type "
            << typeid(float_t).name() << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "for example: " << typeid(float).name() << std::endl;
        throw(1);
    }
    return n * eps / (1.0 - n * eps);
}

int main (void)
{
    std::cout << "gamma = " << gamma(typeid(MYFLOAT), 1000LL) << std::endl;
}
```

The output I get is

```
gamma = gamma: unsupported floating-point type N10__cxxabiv123__fundamental_type_infoE
for example: f
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'int'
```

My question is: what is going on here? What is a fundamental type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `typeid` on a `type_info&`, which is an object you already called `typeid` on. The solution is to replace your conditionals with the following.

```cpp
if (float_t == typeid(double)) {
    eps = mach_eps<double>;
} else if (float_t == typeid(float)) {
    eps = mach_eps<float>;
} else {
    std::cerr << "gamma: unsupported floating-point type "
        << typeid(float_t).name() << std::endl;
    std::cerr << "for example: " << typeid(float).name() << std::endl;
    throw(1);
}
```